# Convert boolean to integer

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to store in a MySql `tinyint(1)`field values that i have already converted from `boolean` with php's `intval()`.

**Example:**

```
$data = true;
$foo = intval($data);
    if (is_numeric($foo)){
        print_r($foo);       
    }
```

The problem is that even if the `$data` is `true` and the `$foo` is numeric, `intval` always returns `0`.

**Update:**

I have this jQuery code in order to take `true/false` if an `html` checkbox is checked.

```
var foo = $('#' + form + ' ' + '[name = "foo"]').is(':checked');
```

then i'm sending the variable `foo` to my controller: (The jQuery code works correctly)

```
$foo = Input::has('foo') ? Input::get('foo'): false;

$newFoo = New Foo();
$newFoo->foo=$foo;
```

Finally in my class:

```
  public $foo;
  print_r(intval($this->foo));
```

Comment: `intval` is for numbers and not for `true` values

Comment: @juergend Ok thank you, what should i do in order to convert `boolean` to `0/1`?

Comment: What? `intval(true)` return `0`?

Comment: @Makis: Google *php bool to int*

Comment: @Leggendario Yes, i'm confused..

Comment: Are you sure? http://3v4l.org/UMGo8

Comment: @juergend But `intval()` uses the common rules for integer casting, right? According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting), `TRUE` should be casted to 1.

Comment: Just give me a minute to update my post to have a better understanding!

Comment: `var_dump($this->foo);` what's return?

Comment: Ok i thing i found my mistake. `var_dump` returns a `string`. Probably because i'sending through ajax to the controller...

Comment: Exactly I've already added the answer... It happens quite often ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `$data` is a string not boolean. You can cast it first and should work